# Outline fonts with true type and opengl core (3.3)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3, freetype

I used the text rendering example from learnopengl.com here:

https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering

I'm trying to change this example to render an outline, but I'm a little lost between all functions to call, and the shader code seems a little tricky.

Here is my attempt:

```
void inittext_stroked() {
    cout << "initializing text, stroken" << endl;

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Compile and setup the shader
    shader = Shader("text.vs", "text.fs");
        //Shader shader("text.vs", "text.fs");

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(WIDTH), 0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(HEIGHT));
    shader.use();
    //shader.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    // FreeType
    FT_Library ft;
    // All functions return a value different than 0 whenever an error occurred
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library" << std::endl;

    string fontfile = base::config.getstr("fontfile");
    cout << fontfile << endl;
    // Load font as face
    FT_Face face;
    // if (FT_New_Face(ft, "DejaVuSansMono.ttf", 0, &face))
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, fontfile.c_str(), 0, &face))
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font " << fontfile << std::endl;

    // stroke, added 
    // void * m_stroker;
    FT_Stroker stroker;
    if (FT_Stroker_New(static_cast<FT_Library>(ft), &stroker) != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to load font \"" << fontfile << "\" (failed to create the stroker)" << std::endl;
        FT_Done_Face(face);
        return;
    }
    // m_stroker = stroker;
    // m_face = face;
    // end added


    // Set size to load glyphs as
    int fontsize;
    //cfg.SET(fontsize);
    // fontsize = 16;
    fontsize = base::config.getvar<int>("fontsize");


    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontsize);
    //FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

    // Disable byte-alignment restriction
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Load first 128 characters of ASCII set
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++)
    {
        // Load character glyph 

        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c,
            //FT_LOAD_RENDER|
            FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP|FT_LOAD_TARGET_NORMAL

        )) // modified, added FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP (also 2 more so 3)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        // added outlining _________________
        float outlineThickness = 10.0f;
        // Retrieve the glyph
        FT_Glyph glyphDesc;
        if (FT_Get_Glyph(face->glyph, &glyphDesc) != 0)
        {
            cerr << "bad return from FT_Get_Glyph" << endl;
            return;
        }

        {
            // FT_Stroker stroker = static_cast<FT_Stroker>(m_stroker);

            FT_Stroker_Set(stroker, static_cast<FT_Fixed>(outlineThickness * static_cast<float>(1 << 6)), FT_STROKER_LINECAP_ROUND, FT_STROKER_LINEJOIN_ROUND, 0);
            FT_Glyph_Stroke(&glyphDesc, stroker, true);
        }

        FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap(&glyphDesc, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL, 0, 1);
        // FT_Bitmap& bitmap = reinterpret_cast<FT_BitmapGlyph>(glyphDesc)->bitmap;

        // added end _________________

        // Generate texture
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
                //GL_RED,
            GL_RG16,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
                //GL_RED,
            GL_RG16,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
        );
        // Set texture options
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        // Now store character for later use
        Character character = {
            texture,
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
            face->glyph->advance.x
        };
        Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    // Destroy FreeType once we're finished
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);


    // Configure VAO/VBO for texture quads
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO_text);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_text);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_text);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_text);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    texts["popo"] = "haha";
}
```

and the shader code:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;
uniform vec3 outlinecolor;

void main()
{   
    // old shader code:
    // vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);
    // color = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;

    vec2 tex = texture2D(text, TexCoords).rg;
    color = vec4(textColor, tex.g)
    +vec4(outlinecolor, tex.g)
    ;
}
```

As you can see I used GL_RG16 instead of RG_RED to have one channel for the fill and one for the outline. I don't understand all those freetype calls, and I'm not familiar with the notion of face, glyph and stroker, and I'm not sure my shader code is adequate either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is not that easy. The first miss understanding is that [`FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap`](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_management.html) won't create 2 channels, one for the stroke outlines and on for the filled body, as you expected.
You have to create 2 bitmaps from the glyph and you have to merge them manually to one bitmap with 2 channels.

An issue is, that the bitmaps won't even have the same size. The "outline" bitmap will be slightly taller, then the "filled" one.

First create the outline bitmap:

```
FT_Error err_code = FT_Load_Char( face, i, FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP | FT_LOAD_TARGET_NORMAL );
if ( err_code != 0 )
{
  // error handling
}

FT_Glyph glyphDescStroke;
err_code = FT_Get_Glyph( face->glyph, &glyphDescStroke );

static double outlineThickness = 2.0;
FT_Stroker_Set( stroker, static_cast<FT_Fixed>(outlineThickness * static_cast<float>(1 << 6)), FT_STROKER_LINECAP_ROUND, FT_STROKER_LINEJOIN_ROUND, 0 );
if ( err_code == 0 )
  err_code = FT_Glyph_Stroke( &glyphDescStroke, stroker, true );

if ( err_code == 0 )
  err_code = FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap( &glyphDescStroke, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL, 0, 1);

FT_BitmapGlyph glyph_bitmap;
FT_Bitmap *bitmap_stroke = nullptr;
if ( err_code == 0 )
{
    glyph_bitmap  = (FT_BitmapGlyph)glyphDescStroke;
    bitmap_stroke = &glyph_bitmap->bitmap;
}
```

Create a temporary buffer with 2 color channels and copy the outline bitmap to the 2nd color channel of the buffer:

```
#include <vector>
```

```
unsigned int cx = 0, cy = 0, ox = 0, oy = 0;

std::vector<unsigned char> buffer
if ( error_code == 0 && bitmap_stroke )
{
    cx = bitmap_stroke->width;
    cy = bitmap_stroke->rows;
    ox = glyph_bitmap->left;
    oy = glyph_bitmap->top;

    buffer = std::vector<unsigned char>(cx * cy * 2, 0); // * 2 -> 2 color channels (red and green)
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < cx * cy; ++ i)
        buffer[i*2 + 1] = bitmap_stroke->buffer[i];      // + 1 -> 2nd color channel
}

FT_Done_Glyph( glyphDescStroke );
```

Create the "filled" bitmap:

```
FT_Glyph glyphDescFill;
err_code = FT_Get_Glyph( face->glyph, &glyphDescFill );
if ( err_code == 0 )
    err_code = FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap( &glyphDescFill, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL, 0, 1);

FT_Bitmap *bitmap_fill = nullptr;
if ( err_code == 0 )
{
    FT_BitmapGlyph glyph_bitmap = (FT_BitmapGlyph)glyphDescFill;
    bitmap_fill = &glyph_bitmap->bitmap;
}
```

Add the "filled" bitmap to the 1st color channel of the buffer:

```
if ( err_code == 0 && bitmap_fill )
{
    unsigned int cx_fill  = bitmap_fill->width;
    unsigned int cy_fill  = bitmap_fill->rows;
    unsigned int offset_x = (cx - cx_fill) / 2; // offset because the bitmap my be smaller, 
    unsigned int offset_y = (cy - cy_fill) / 2; // then the former

    for ( unsigned int y = 0; y < cy_fill; ++ y )
    {
        for ( unsigned int x = 0; x < cx_fill; ++ x )
        {
            unsigned int i_source = y * cx_fill + x;
            unsigned int i_target = (y + offset_y) * cx + x + offset_x;
            buffer[i_target*2 + 0] = bitmap_fill->buffer[i_source]; // + 0 -> 1st color channel
        }
    }
}

FT_Done_Glyph( glyphDescFill );
```

When you load the buffer to the texture object, the you have toe set the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` parameter, because the glyph bitmap `buffer` is tightly packed and a row  of the bitmap may not be aligned to 4 bytes. See [`glPixelStore`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml).

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glPixelStore( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 ); // of course 2 will work too (2 channels)     
glTexImage2D( 
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RG8, // 2 channels each with 8 bits
    cx,
    cy,
    GL_RG,  // "GL_RG" - "GL_RG16" is not a valid format
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    buffer.data() );
glPixelStore( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4 );

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Add the character data to the data structure:

```
Character character = {
    texture,
    glm::ivec2(cx, cy),
    glm::ivec2(ox, oy),
    face->glyph->advance.x
};
Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
```

The GLSL code, which draw a glyph with a separate color for the outline and the filled interior, which uses the GLSL function [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) may look like this:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;
uniform vec3 outlinecolor;

void main()
{  
    vec3 fill_col    = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // e.g blue
    vec3 outline_col = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // e.g red

    vec2 tex = texture2D(text, TexCoords).rg;
    float fill    = tex.r;
    float outline = tex.g;

    float alpha    = max( fill, outline );
    vec3 mix_color = mix( mix(vec3(0.0), fill_col, fill), outline_col, outline );

    color = vec4(mix_color, alpha);
}
```

---

Preview with *pixlim(2).ttf* font, from the repository which you linked in the comments:

[image: text]

Comment: Did you test this code? I managed to get it to work, but characters are not aligned https://i.imgur.com/HNM82IA.png Using other valid TTF than deja fonts crashes.

Comment: @jokoon Yes, I tested it, but not that part of the code. I tested the part which creates the bitmaps and the shader in an existing example in my test suite. I'll have a look on your issue.

Comment: @jokoon The setup of the `Character` structure has to be adapted, too. See the changes to the answer.

Comment: Text is aligned now! Unfortunately it's crashing inside ftobjs.c at line 2955 when I load a TTF font I made...

Comment: @jokoon I tested the code with *FreeSans.ttf*, *37043_SYMBOL.ttf* (greek letters) and *Pacifico.ttf* (script) and it worked fine.

Comment: https://github.com/jokoon/eio/blob/master/__data__/fonts/mine/pixlim(2).ttf this will crash... Although I would not know why, and I guess you're not a freetype dev. It was generated with this online font generator: https://www.pentacom.jp/pentacom/bitfontmaker2/

Comment: @jokoon *pixlim(2).ttf* seems to work for me. May be it depends on the version of the library. I'm using version 2.9

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qCRtE20.png top text is rendering with SFML, same font, bottom is with opengl. I tried different values of the outline value, but the text looks ghostly and hollow... What do you think?

Comment: SFML is using FT_LOAD_FORCE_AUTOHINT, and I've seen an other font shader do something like `fill = clamp(fill * 2.0, 0.0, 1.0);` https://wildfiregames.com/forum/index.php?/topic/17365-freetype-ttf-fonts-in-opengl/ . In your screenshot, your result fill space seems good... I might be missing something... What outline value/font size are you using?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MmLuTHu.png pretty satisfied with the result, thanks! The detail is setting outline to 64 even at small size, not exactly sure why, but I guess it defines a radius. I did not use clamping. Last issue is kerning, as you can see a lot of outlines being cut off. I have no idea how to fix this, but the SFML code might help.

Comment: Although it doesn't seem to be a kerning issue, it's just textures overriding alpha, for some reason...

Comment: FYI if you want to display an example string with all letters look up a pangram like "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way you can do it is to draw each letter a second time with some scaling and a different color in the same position. Just make sure you draw them in the correct order (first the scaled up and then the normal one)